# Limit the loop for handlebarjs

Tags: c#, angular, handlebars.js

If we have the following context:

**C#**

```
List<people> lst = new List<people>();
lst.add(new people{Name='mark'});
lst.add(new people{Name='james'});
lst.add(new people{Name='anthony'});
```

Let's consider a helper that will generate an HTML list:

```
 {{#list people}}{{firstName}} {{lastName}}{{/list}}
```

Here, how to limit the loop to take only 2 persons (also wants random persons from the list if possible), instead of iterating through the complete array.

Reference: http://handlebarsjs.com

**Update:**

I am using the Handebars.Net reference: https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net

Actually I am passing the people object from c# like:

```
 var Template = Handlebars.Compile(lst);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either pass two elements you want to the handlebars creating a new array from your original data.(which gives you complete control over how to select two persons)

Or you can try to implement a handler for this like:

## Javascript

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(items, len, options) {
  var out = "<ul>";

  for(var i=0, l=len; i<l; i++) {
    out = out + "<li>" + options.fn(items[i]) + "</li>";
  }

  return out + "</ul>";
});
```

and use it like

```
{{#list people 2}}{{firstName}} {{lastName}}{{/list}}
```

In here 2 is your limit, You can change it as you wish

## C#

For C# Handlebars.Net version looks like follows

```
var data = new {
 people = new [] {
  new {
   name = "Karen"
  },
  new {
   name = "Kasun"
  },
  new {
   name = "Jon"
  }
 }
};

string source = @"{{#list 2}}{{name}}{{/list}}";

HandlebarsBlockHelper _listhelper = (TextWriter output, HelperOptions options, dynamic context, object[] arguments) => {
 // take 2 as argument in example
 int len = Int32.Parse(arguments[0] as string);
 output.WriteSafeString("<ul>");
 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  output.WriteSafeString("<li>");
  // pass name from people object to {{name}}
  options.Template(output, context.people[i]);
  output.WriteSafeString("</li>");
 }

 output.WriteSafeString("</ul>");
};


Handlebars.RegisterHelper("list", _listhelper);
var template = Handlebars.Compile(source);
var result = template(data);
```

C# Fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/gUr2VA

Hope it helps.

Reference: [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: I am using c#.  How to implement a handler for this like?

Comment: The question is unclear, it references to handlebar.js not mentioning c#. You will need to edit it accordingly. This answer has implied you are using JS :)

Comment: are you using Handebars.Net ?please mention that too

Comment: yes, I am using Handebars.Net, sorry! I have updated my requirement.

Comment: answer updated with a fiddle, error handling and others are left for you, just get the idea :) read this again https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net

Comment: Thank you very much, Kasper!!. I will check it out when at home.